# How to import an Azure SQL Database using PowerShell in AzureResourceManager mode?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure

I am working on a PowerShell script where I am using only `Azure Resource Manager` (ARM) [mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554330.aspx) to create an `Azure SQL Database` using `*.bacpac` file from a `Storage Account`.

My issue is that I can't find a PowerShell Command that does exactly the same as the [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546725.aspx) one, but in `Azure Service Management` (ASM) mode.

Best Wishes, Oleg

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from Microsoft Support:

---

*Unfortunately, there is no equivalent cmdlet in ARM mode. However, good news is that, in approximately a week, switch mode is deprecating and you should be able to use the* `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport` *ASM command.*

*Here is the article that talks about that:*

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell

---

It seems after  08-Oct-2015 I can mix both ASM and ARM commands in one single mode until Microsoft release something like `Start-AzureRMSqlDatabaseImport`